# How to enable non-free algorythms (SIFT, SURF) of OpenCV for Python?

Tags: python, opencv, sift, keypoint

I compiled the **opencv-master** by adding extra modules from **opencv_contrib-master** with **CMake** based on the following guide: 
http://pravo-u.ru/blog/%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-opencv-4-1-0-pre-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-python3-%D0%B2-windows-7-x64-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-cmake/

These videos also show the same procedure: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=By-PKbWDZNk
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fIpTks0G2m0

CMake compilation is done correctly. In folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\~v2 there is a cv2.cp37-win32.pyd file. 
I am just a little bit confused about the last step, which files do I need to copy where? What settings do I need to do?

Can anybody help me with that? 
Python in VS Code can not see cv2 yet.

My built Opencv is here: D:\OpenCV\opencvbuild

I use Windows7.